# xml parsing into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, xml, loops, xml-parsing, text-parsing

I want to parse an xml file in R. It's a Germany parliamentary debate. I managed to get a list of all the `<rede>` (speech) elements.

Now I want to put the name of the speaker and the speech as a single string into a dataframe.
I then want to print the number of speeches, and the content of the first speech.

This is the code I have so far:

```r
session <-read_html("https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/909520/ccbb1b470836b419e0e0ab726b679a99/20052-data.xml")
# session Sep 09 2022


# list of all the <rede> elements. 
speeches <- session %>% 
  html_elements("rede") %>% 
  html_text2() 

# name of the speaker, and speech as a single string
bundestag_links <- session %>% html_elements("rede")
bundestag_links

# list of lastnames (nachname) and first names (vorname)
nachname <- bundestag_links %>% html_elements("nachname") %>% html_text2()
nachname 
vorname <- bundestag_links %>% html_elements("vorname") %>% html_text2()
vorname

speaker <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, vorname=vorname, nachname=nachname))  
unique(speaker$nachname)
unique(speaker$vorname)
speaker <- speaker %>% 
  distinct()
```

There are 39 speeches but 51 speakers. Some are dublicates, as some people speak twice so deleting them actually didn't make sense.

I know there is also an ID for the speech and one for the speaker, so I extracted that info too.

```r
# speaker ID
pattern_redner_id <- "redner id=........(\\d)"
redner_id <- bundestag_links %>% 
    str_extract(pattern_redner_id) %>% 
    str_remove_all("redner id=")
redner_id

# speech ID
pattern_rede_id <- "ID........(\\d)"
rede_id <- str_extract(bundestag_links, pattern_rede_id)
rede_id
```

I managed to get one of the speeches into an individual string too.

```r
speakerspeech_1 <- bundestag_links[1] %>% html_elements("p[klasse!=redner]") %>% paste(collapse = " ")
speakerspeech_1
```

I'm new to parsing and relative new to coding and don't know how to combine this information into one dataframe.

I appreciate any help and recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using XPath with `xml2` package to parse needed content under every `<rede>` node and bind data together

```r
library(xml2)

url <- paste0(
  "https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/909520/",
  "ccbb1b470836b419e0e0ab726b679a99/20052-data.xml"
)
doc <- read_xml(url)

# RETREIVE ALL rede NODES
redes <- xml_find_all(doc, "//rede")

# BUILD A DATA FRAME OF CONTENT UNDER EACH rede
redes_dfs <- lapply(
  redes, function(r)
  data.frame(
    speech_id = xml_attr(r, "id"),
    speaker_id = sapply(xml_find_all(r, "p/redner/@id"), xml_text),
    speaker = paste(
      sapply(xml_find_all(r, "p/redner/name/vorname"), xml_text),
      sapply(xml_find_all(r, "p/redner/name/nachname"), xml_text)
    ),
    speech = paste(
      sapply(xml_find_all(r, "p[position() > 1]"), xml_text),
      collapse = " "
    )
  )
)

# BIND ALL DATA FRAMES AND DE-DUPE DATA
speeches_df <- unique(do.call(rbind, redes_dfs))
```

**Output**

```r
str(speeches_df)
'data.frame':   40 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ speech_id : chr  "ID205200100" "ID205200200" "ID205200300" "ID205200400" ...
 $ speaker_id: chr  "999990119" "11004917" "11005200" "11004749" ...
 $ speaker   : chr  "Nancy Faeser" "Alexander Throm" "Jamila Schäfer" "Martin Hess" ...
 $ speech    : chr  "Danke schön, Frau Präsidentin...
```

[image: DataFrame View]